# How to test fingerprint on emulator in ui tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation, android-fingerprint-api

In ui test I run:

```
 InstrumentationRegistry
                .getInstrumentation()
                .uiAutomation
                .executeShellCommand("-e emu finger touch 45146572")//or"adb -e emu finger touch 45146572"
```

and then I have got exception:

```
*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: Thread-10
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running shell command
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection$1.run(UiAutomationConnection.java:295)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [-e, emu, finger, touch, 45146572] Working Directory: null Environment: null
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:247)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:190)
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection$1.run(UiAutomationConnection.java:281)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:247) 
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:190) 
    at android.app.UiAutomationConnection$1.run(UiAutomationConnection.java:281)
```

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You can't run `adb` commands on the device or emulator

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Do you have any solution for emulating finger touch on emulator in ui tests?

Comment: I have same question as @AdamMiśtal